# How to deserialize a JSON field with an @ and . in the name to a Typescript interface?

Tags: json, typescript, axios, deserialization, json-deserialization

I am using Microsoft Entra ID to do single sign-on for my React app. I am following the tutorials [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/tutorial-single-page-app-react-register-app).

I'm able to get the reply from the Microsoft Graph API, which has the following reply:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
    "businessPhones": [
        "1-234-5678"
    ],
    "displayName": "EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine",
    "givenName": "EJoshuaS",
    "jobTitle": null,
    "mail": "my.mail@mail.com",
    "mobilePhone": "1-234-5678",
    "officeLocation": "Undisclosed location",
    "preferredLanguage": null,
    "surname": "Stand with Ukraine",
    "userPrincipalName": "principalname@mydomain.com",
    "id": "67d35976-d72a-41ef-875d-a49ee599ea3d"
}
```

Right now, I do the call like this:

```
let result = await axios.get<ILoggedOnUserData>("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me", {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
    }
})
```

I'm somewhat confused as to how to include `@odata.context` as a field in the interface. Is it possible?

```
export interface ILoggedOnUserData {
    // My question is: How do I include @odata.context here?
    businessPhones: string[]
    displayName: string
    givenName: string
    id: string
    jobTitle: string | null
    mail: string
    mobilePhone: string
    officeLocation: string
    preferredLanguage: string | null
    surname: string
    userPrincipalName: string
}
```

Can someone clarify the proper way to handle this?

Comment: Same as you would add key with '@' and '.' to regular JS object, by enclosing it in quotes